# Store JavaScript function in cookie?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

Is it possible to save a JavaScript function in a cookie? If so, how?

For example, I have user settings for keyboard shortcuts, but the behavior associated with each keystroke could be custom. I was hoping to save these potentially unique and user-specific mappings in a cookie.

I'm currently using Angular 1.4.7 to put the cookie. The data it returns strips out the function.

Comment: cookies just save a string, so you would need to save the string of the function and then load it with an eval, but wouldn´t recommend it. Not sure if there is a better way

Comment: If you're using angularjs, like your post suggests, see my updated answer below. It's a lot safer than using eval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *shouldn't* save the function in a cookie. Instead, you should create an object with all the possible methods the user can execute, and instead store the method name, i.e.:

```
var customUserFunctions = {
    someMethod: function() { ... },
    ...
};
```

And then store `"someMethod"` in the cookie, and call it with `customUserFunctions[variableHoldingSomeMethodString]()`.

**That being said**, this is how you would store the function in a cookie:

```
// Define your function
var myFunc = function() { console.log("I'm a stored function!"); };
// Turn it into a string
var myFuncString = myFunc.toString();
// Store it in your cookie
document.cookie = myFuncString;
// get your function back
var myCookieFunc = eval(document.cookie);
// call it
myCookieFunc();
```

Note that this will create a security vulnerability in which an attacker can modify a cookie and your code will execute whatever function(s) they put in there.

Comment: Using a look-up was the approach I took. Very clean, no security risk.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't store a function on a cookie. You could, though, store a reference to the function in an associative array, and store the key in a cookie instead. That way, when the cookie is loaded, use the key to 're-load' the function.

EDIT:

Building on my first answer, the ideal (IMO) solution would be to define a factory which provides the same kind of functionality. That way it can be injected into your modules as required. For example, you could do (rough demo):

```
app.factory('getUserFunctions', function(){
    return function(keyFromCookie){
      switch (keyFromCookie) {
        case "hello": return function(){
            return "Hello, world!";
        }
        case "goodbye": return function() {
            return "Goodbye, crule world";
        }
        default: return undefined;
      }
    };
});
```

and call the factory with a token to get a reference to one of the functions you defined:

```
$scope.fromFactory = getUserFunctions("goodbye");
```

Comment: Well, you actually can store code in a cookie which can be evaluated to make a function.  It's probably not the right way to solve the OP's issue, but it can be done.

Comment: @jfriend00: And you'd really have to worry about XSS capabilites of such a solution

Comment: @Bergi - And, like I already said in my comment, it's probably not the right way to solve the problem.  I'm reacting to this answer's first sentence which is simply wrong.

Comment: You're storing a sring then, not a `function`. IMO a factory type solution would be the best way.

Comment: A factory solution is better than a string function, agreed. However, I prefer the simplicity of a simple map as in the accepted answer. If there's a reason to use switch/case over key: function, I'd like to know.

Comment: I'd just like to point out I was actually the first to give that solution and was down voted. You could of course, use a map/associative array in place of the switch, and still have the benefit of being able to inject the factory wherever you need it. The benefit of using a switch in this case is you can have a default case, which may be preferable to returning undefined if the map does not contain the given value. In addition, you could also implement some error handling in the default case (which admittedly you could also do without a switch) to catch potential future errors.

Comment: Good point about the default case. Also, I do not know why other responses were downvoted; I upvoted your response so it wasn't negative :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use the Function object. Save the content of the function in the cookie than retrieve it, than pass it to the constructor.

```
var str = "{alert(1)}";
var f = new Function(str);
f();
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d37qzet6/

But I don't think this is the best approach in this scenario.

Comment: No need for the braces.